# Simple repetition in Ruby regexp not working

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out why Ruby's repetition for pattern matching isn't returning what I think it should.

Here's the simplest version of my problem:

```
str="Hello"

# Matches "Hello" correctly
pattern1=/[A-Z][a-z]*/
r = pattern1.match(str)
puts("[#{r}]")
# prints "[Hello]"

# Matches "e" correctly
pattern2=/[a-z]/
r = pattern2.match(str)
puts("[#{r}]")
# prints "[e]"

# Should match "ello" but doesn't
pattern3=/[a-z]*/
r = pattern3.match(str)
puts("[#{r}]")
# prints "[]"
```

[According to the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Repetition), the * match should be greedy.  It doesn't seem to be.  What am I doing wrong?

For what it's worth, grep (and PHP) seem to behave as expected:

```
$ echo "Hello" | grep "[A-Z][a-z]*"
Hello
```

I'm using ruby 2.6.5p114 if that helps.

Comment: Your question is about `pattern3`, but the example you gave of "correct behaviour in PHP and grep" is using `pattern1`. You're comparing apples with oranges.

Comment: Every regexp engine will return the same result for `pattern3`. `*` always means "zero or more", not "one or more".

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I don't get the same results with grep and pattern3:

echo "Hello" | grep "[a-z]*" shows "ello" as the pattern that matched.

Also, the Ruby docs I linked to in the OP specifically say that the * is a greedy match.  Thus, if it can match 0 or more, it should match as many as possible.  It doesn't appear to be.

Comment: Default `grep` will highlight ALL of the matches, whereas ruby's `match` method only returns the first result. And you are misunderstanding what a "greedy" operator is, in this context.

Comment: Forget the word "greedy" for now; it's not important here. `/[a-z]*/` just says "zero or more lower case letters". So the first match is at the start of the string "Hello", *before* the letter `H`, where there are no lower case letters. Then the *second* match is *after* the letter H, where there are 4 lower case letters.

Comment: If you want to understand why the operator is called "greedy", then I suggest googling it - as that's a somewhat separate question.

Answer (score 4):

Reason for this behaviour is that `/[a-z]*/` matches the character group `[a-z]` **zero** or more times. The `.match` method matches the first thing it can find.

```
/[a-z]*/.match("Hello")
```

Will thus match before the `"H"` since it matches the criteria of a length of zero `[a-z]` characters. The second match would be `"ello"`.

```
"Hello".scan(/[a-z]*/) #=> ["", "ello", ""]
```

You might want to use the `+` quantifier to match one or more times.

Comment: Thanks. The docs I linked to in the OP specifically say that the match should be greedy.  Your answer is what I'm seeing, but it doesn't appear to match what the docs say the behavior should be.

I mean, if "*" always matches 0 or more, and the default is to accept 0 matches, then in what sense is * useful?  Every pattern matches every string 0 or more times.

Comment: The `*` is indeed greedy by default, but can't match more since the next character is `H` which doesn't match the criteria. Reasons to use `*` is when you want to allow certain characters that might or might not be present. It's almost never used on its own. A good example would be `Hello World!*`. Which matches `Hello World` followed by as much `!` chars as possible, or none if not present. Or take a Ruby variable, which may not start with a capital or number `[a-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` meaning it must start with `[a-z_]` but can consist of only one char so the other part is optional.

Comment: You could also change your regex to `(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]*`, which says: Match `[a-z]` zero or more times, but only if directly after `[A-Z]`. Which does the same as `[a-z]+` for your provided example: `"Hello".scan(/(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]*/) #=> ["ello"]` and `"Hello".scan(/[a-z]+/) #=> ["ello"]`, but differs when you have no lowercase letters: `"H".scan(/(?<=[A-Z])[a-z]*/) #=> [""]` and `"H".scan(/[a-z]+/) #=> []`.